# What are the exact hardware requirements for Moodle installation on a large University?

Tags: server, moodle, system-administration, server-administration, lms

Our university is planning to install the latest stable moodle as our primary LMS. The university has 20,000 students. Based on our initial projection, we have an average of 250 subjects open for every semester, 700 faculties, and around 6,000 concurrent student users. With this kind of requirement, we wanted to install moodle on a dedicated or on a cluster server but we are still confused with the exact hardware specifications to purchase. For example, RAM, Hard disk, CPU, and bandwidth allocation.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you may need only a memory optimized convertible reserved instance (EC2). I have installed Moodle for several institutions. Please feel free to contact me if needed.